# Scipy.optimize.curvefit log function

Tags: python, logging, scipy

I'm trying to generate equation parameters for this equation:

y = -log((a+bx)/(c+x))

I've got a sample set of data for x, y and a, b and c.

When I do the following:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import log as log
from scipy import exp as exp
import numpy as np

#Should generate: a = 2.22726000005 , b = 0.1073, c = 2.68937000008

a=1
b=1e-6
c=1

yarr = np.array([0.31776,0.30324,0.28148,0.2651,0.24328,0.22144,0.19799,0.17431,0.14685,0.11521])
xarr = np.array([0.250,0.225,0.200,0.175,0.150,0.125,0.100,0.075,0.050,0.025])

def func(x, a, b, c):

    return (log(c+x)-log(a+(b*x)))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,  xarr, yarr, (a,b,c))

print "a = %s , b = %s, c = %s" % (popt[0], popt[1], popt[2])
```

This should give me:

a = 2.22726000005 , b = 0.1073, c = 2.68937000008

but what I get is:

a = 0.37366276487 , b = 0.415297976794, c = 0.406353416622

which gives a nice curve, but it's nowhere near the correct values.

I've read several similar issues here, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

Any tips?

Thanks
Lemmy

Comment: What makes you think the values should be the ones you suggest? The fit seems much better with the ones `curve_fit` produces.

Comment: @xnx, the data and equation come from a peer-reviewed scientific paper, and plotting the data (in Excel) for both the paper's abc values and curvefit's abc values shows that the agreement is poor. I've found the paper has a mistake, the xarr values are out by a factor of 10, I should add the line:

'code'xarr=arr*10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the supplied data nearly so well with the values you supply as with the values `curve_fit` produces, so perhaps you need to supply more information about the problem:

```
In [48]: pylab.plot(xarr, yarr, label='data')
In [49]: pylab.plot(xarr,func(xarr, *popt), label='curve_fit')
In [50]: ap, bp, cp = 2.22726000005, 0.1073, 2.68937000008
In [51]: pylab.plot(xarr,func(xarr, ap,bp,cp), label='supplied a,b,c')
In [52]: pylab.legend()
In [53]: pylab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response, it reassured me that curvefit was actually working correctly and that made me look at what could be the cause of the disagreement. Since I was plotting in Excel (I can't download modules and don't have any for plotting - thanks IT!) I therefore assumed it was an Excel issue. The problem was that LOG in excel is base 10, whereas     'Scipy.log' is natural. The paper also used base 10 implicitly, but I never checked it explicity. Changing 'from scipy import log as log' to 'from scipy import log10 as log' gives the expected parameters.